# What is the best way to get depth values from kinect?

Tags: ros, kinect, depth, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros with the kinect drivers in ubuntu and have it all up and running.i'm new to ros.

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is this:  extract the distance in millimetres of a particular point in an RGB image. So what ever the kinect sees in front of it I want to be able to get the depth values out of it. i'm not sure which topic I need to use and

I had a look at:

depth/image_raw (sensor_msgs/Image)
Raw image from device. Contains uint16 depths in mm.

But this seems to return each pixel as a max value of 256 and not a u16bit int when viewing the topic by running rostopic echo /camera/depth/image_raw ... how do I convert this depth into millimetres? is the the best one to use at all? or should I use something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32855/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-depth-values-from-kinect?/) by [Maltenrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2265/maltenrazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on 2012-04-30**:
If you want to extract depth values from an RGB image, you'd probably want to use a registered depth image, i.e. one in which the Depth values are aligned with RGB values. So try using: camera/depth_registered/image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [depth_image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/depth_image_proc) and [openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch). Also do a search here on answers.ros.org for kinect. Between these three things, it should give you a good head start ... good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/5515/fairy/) on 2013-07-25**:
the depth values that obtain by kinect driver is actually a no. of streams that continuously changing even if kinect remain stationary can u tell me plz y is it so?

secondly if i want to access the depth of particular point out of the depth of all points that is seen by kinect, how can i do it? plz guide me

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-06-25**:
@fairy check my answer below to get depth value at a specific point